# OOM in TensorFlow DQN with large action set

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, out-of-memory, reinforcement-learning

Below code is for Deep Q Network in TensorFlow.

When running this, OOM error is occurred in initializing TensorFlow variables. I think this is because my experiment model has much larger action set (ex. 3125000 actions). I made my own simulator which returns states as tuple (about 50~100 numbers), so I don't need to use convolutional layers.

The error message is like this:

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:967] failed to alloc 17179869184 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1179869184
```

How can I deal with this problem?
Please help me...

System environment is Ubuntu 16.04 with TITAN X (Pascal)

```
    class DQN:
        def __init__(self, n_features, n_action, lr, dr, max_e_greedy, e_increment, replace_target_iter, memory_size, batch_size):
            self.n_features = n_features
            self.n_actions = n_action
            self.lr = lr
            self.gamma = dr
            self.max_e = max_e_greedy
            self.replace_target_iter = replace_target_iter
            self.memory_size = memory_size
            self.batch_size = batch_size
            self.e = 0
            self.e_increment = e_increment
            self.learn_step = 0
            self.memory = np.zeros((self.memory_size, n_features*2 + 2))
            self.cost_his=[]

            self.build_net()
            t_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='target_net')
            e_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='eval_net')

            with tf.variable_scope('soft_replacement'):
                self.target_replace_op=[tf.assign(t,e) for t,e in zip(t_params,e_params)]

            self.sess=tf.Session()
            self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        def build_net(self):
            self.s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_features], name='s')  # input State
            self.s_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_features], name='s_')  # input Next State
            self.r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, ], name='r')  # input Reward
            self.a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ], name='a')  # input Action

            w_initializer, b_initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.3), tf.constant_initializer(0.1)

            with tf.variable_scope('eval_net'):
                e1 = tf.layers.dense(self.s, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='e1')
                e2 = tf.layers.dense(e1, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='e2')
                #e3 = tf.layers.dense(e2, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='e3')
                #e4 = tf.layers.dense(e3, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='e4')
                self.q_eval=tf.layers.dense(e2, self.n_actions, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='q')

            with tf.variable_scope('target_net'):
                t1 = tf.layers.dense(self.s_, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t1')
                t2 = tf.layers.dense(t1, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t2')
                #t3 = tf.layers.dense(t2, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t3')
                #t4 = tf.layers.dense(t3, 800, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t4')
                self.q_next=tf.layers.dense(t2, self.n_actions, kernel_initializer=w_initializer, bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t5')

            with tf.variable_scope('q_target'):
                q_target = self.r + self.gamma * tf.reduce_max(self.q_next, axis=1, name='Qmax_s_')
                self.q_target = tf.stop_gradient(q_target)
            with tf.variable_scope('q_eval'):
                a_indices = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(self.a)[0], dtype=tf.int32), self.a], axis=1)
                self.q_eval_wrt_a = tf.gather_nd(params=self.q_eval, indices=a_indices)    # shape=(None, )
            with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
                self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.q_target, self.q_eval_wrt_a, name='TD_error'))
            with tf.variable_scope('train'):
                self._train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: The error says it couldn't allocate 16 GB of GPU RAM, your GPU doesn't have that much RAM, so what is the question?

Comment: so is it saying 16 GB of VRAM is required to build network? The error occurred at 
    self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 

if it is due to too large network, is there any ways to reduce the size? Actually, my input is just a tuple with 50 ~ 100 number of integer (maximum number is smaller than 50)

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow tries to allocate a fraction `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` of the GPU memory to the process.  (See the comments in the [GPUOptions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto) of the Tensorflow source). The default setting for this is 95%. If that value is changed to a value your GPU cannot handle, you might see the `CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error. This error can also be raised if another process is using the GPU and taking up memory that Tensorflow thinks it will have.

If you want to avoid using CPU, you can true using `allow_growth=True`. When you use `allow_growth = True`, the GPU memory is not preallocated and will be able to grow as you need it.